# Flyway with SQL server integrated security

Tags: jdbc, flyway, jtds

I'm attempting to use jdbc plus jtds to connect to SQL server and run flyway migrations. Its a requirement that the connection use integrated security. Is this supported in flyway? If I specify `integratedsecurity=true` and don't specify a username and password I am prompted to enter one when I run the command line `flyway migrate` suggesting that its ignoring my setting to use integrated security.

Comment: I've raised this as an issue https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2679 and hopefully will be resolved in v6.2.4

Comment: Indeed, now shipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway doesn't support it out of the box. [It's a known limitation](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1646).

There is [a manual workaround explained on the website](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver#windows-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Now works out of the box -> https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/supported-databases/sql-server

> Windows Authentication
>
> Windows Authentication, also known as Integrated Security, is enabled
> by amending your JDBC connection string to set
> integratedSecurity=true.
>
> Syntax:
> jdbc:sqlserver://:;databaseName=;integratedSecurity=true.
>
> Example:
> jdbc:sqlserver://server01:1234;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).